# How I can insert an existing object in the Data base LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I need insert an existing object in the DataBase

```
public void AddResolutionObject(Resolution resolution)
{
    Context.Resolution.AddObject(resolution);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I have an error with the method:

```
AddObject(resolution);
```

because the object already exist in the database, but I reallly need insert another object with the same records exept the primary key of course

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you passing in for "resolution"? Is it an EF proxy object or a new instance of "Resolution"?

Comment: Create a new instance of that object with the sane property values, add it then save.

Comment: Do you get any exception when doing this?

Comment: is a new instance of Resolution

Comment: @AbrahamRivera how is the primary key of the Resolution entity composed?

Comment: is an int identity @user449689

Comment: There are many questions about cloning entities with Entity Framework. Please take a look first.

Answer (score 0):

In EDMX designer properties set for the primary key column

```
 StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity
```